# Fonts altered after ghostscript conversion

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

I'm using GS to convert PS Files into PDF and on some PS files created with the driver Toshiba Printer 2 and i have an alteration of the font.

The text appears upside down and when i copy it and paste it, it looks like binary code.

When I try to see the PS files renderer with GSView 5.0 and i don't have theses alteration.

I try to change/add parameters of GS Conversion but i don't find the problem source. I try to change GS version but i have the same problem with 8.60,8.71,9.02 and 9.16 version.

Which paramaters of conversion could be changed to solve my problem ? I look at http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm without sucess.

I used this command line to convert ps files : "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.16\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q dPDFA -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFTER -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="outputfile.pdf" -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage "inputfile.ps"

I don't undestrand why in GS View 5.0 the PDf render is OK.

PS : When i open the PS File in GS View I have an DSC error

Regards.

Comment: I used this command line to convert ps files : "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.16\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q dPDFA -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFTER -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="outputfile.pdf" -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage "inputfile.ps"

Answer (score 0):

This question was duplicated as a bug in the Ghostscript Bugzilla bug tracker. For anyone interested in the resolution the URL is:

http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=696109